# Chart point and drawline

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I want create chart with 3 points and then draw a line. it will be as following image
![c# form chart][1]
But my coding barely draw line and no points. please help

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point[] pts = { new Point(150, 12), new Point(130, 15), new Point(160, 18) };
        //int count = 0;

      //   pts[count] = new Point((int)NumericUpDown1.Value, (int)NumericUpDown2.Value);
        for (int i = 0; i < pts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3), pts[i - 1], pts[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3), pts[i], pts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where'd the example chart image go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem in your code is hard-coded `pts[1]`. You should use `pts[i]` instead. And remember - array indexing in C# starts from zero.

Also you don't need to create graphics on each iteration. Declare local variable and move it outside loop. And instead of checking loop value on each iteration you can move first point drawing also outside loop. Then you will be able to process other points in same way:

```
var g = this.CreateGraphics();
var blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);

g.DrawLine(blackPen, pts[0], pts[0]);

for(i = 1; i < pts.Length; i++)
   g.DrawLine(blackPen, pts[i - 1], pts[i]);
```

---

Note: you have tagged question with Linq tag. Of course you can use Linq to create pairs of points, and use this pairs to draw lines:

```
var lines = pts.Zip(pts.Skip(1), (a,b) => new { a, b });

foreach(var line in lines)
    g.DrawLine(blackPen, line.a, line.b);
```

Comment: -3 : Every Winforms drawing mistake there is: You should use DrawLines and also the Paint event! And you should dispose of the Pen..!

Comment: @TaW you see event handler in my answer? answer is not valid? usually I use Pen/Brush and other gdi object as class field and dispose them on form dispose. -1 for marking valid answer as 'not useful' which is a lie. You can not upvote or write comments if you have something to improve

Comment: You keep using CreateGraphics which clearly indicates that you don't use the paint event. Therefore your answer is not only not useful but harmful. As for your downvoting my answer as not helpful in revenge, this is clearly in violation of all SO voting rules. And you calling me a liar leaves me (almost) speechless..

Comment: @TaW 1) I'm fixing problem which OP facing. Not naming, not other stuff. If OP has `CreateGraphics` method, then probably he had reason to use that method. I do not modify code outside of drawing lines logic. I'm answering question AND giving some advises. 2) I do not see any violations of SO rules. I find your answer not helpful for OP problem. You just rewrote all code and give it as is. I stated this in comments to your answer

Answer (score -1):

Here is the correct code:

```
// keep your data at class level:
// lists are more flexible than arrays:
List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();

 // all drawing in the paint event:
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // put the pen creation in a using scope:
    using ( Pen Pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3f) )
    {  
        // make the corners nicer:
        pen.MiterLimit = pen.Width / 2f;

        // drawing all lines in one call greatly improves quality.
        // we need at least two points:
        if (pts.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines( Pen, pts);
    }
}

// trigger the drawing when needed, eg when you have added more points:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // maybe add more points..
    pts.AddRange( new Point[]  
                { new Point(150, 12), new Point(130, 15), new Point(160, 18) } );

    // trigger the paint event
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Consider drawing onto a `Panel`! This will allow you to move it around and place all controls independently on your `Form`..

If you are serious about creating a chart do consider using the `Chart` control in the Data bin of the toolbox!

It features everything a real chart needs including labeled axes and many style of display.

To use your data all it takes are these few lines:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
//..
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Legends.Clear();
    chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
    chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;

    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(130, 15);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(150, 12);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(160, 18);
}
```

Note that I have ordered the points but that is not necessary for all charttypes. I use Fastline and with you original order it works as well. It can even display several points wit the same X-Value..! And of curse it automatically scales..

Also note that the Chart displays Y-Values in the natural way, i.e. from bottom to top, whereas GDI draws from top down!

Here is a screenshot of the both ways to show a Chart:

[image]

Comment: -X lot of problems. This answer is not related to OP question. There is NO given answer to OP problem. Naming is awful - `pts` instead of `points`, button1, button2 etc. Also each button click will add another set of same points to `pts` list. This is a bug.

Comment: Instead of writng comments you should read my code including the comments. And of course one should keep naming if it help the OP to relate to his project code.. No bugs to fix here.

Comment: Instead of arguing you should read my comments and OP question. Also it would be nice for you to read **very carefully** [description of downvoting and when it should be applied](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: I have. But have you? Maybe you have forgotten a few things.. And no, I won't argue with you any longer.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not. No surprise. But good to hear you stopped arguing. Maybe next time you will follow SO reccomindations

Comment: Go and look for a mirror!